# Get values for absent records for each employee

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

**Table 1 - EmployeeCommitment**
This table describes the percentage of time commitment for employees.

Columns:

- **Date**: The date they commit their time to.
- **Employee**: employee username
- **Commitment**: E.g. 20% means the employee is planning to commit 20% of their daily time on work

**Table 2 - Calendar**
This table is basically a calendar with a row for each day of the year.

Columns:

- **Calendar_Date**
- **Include**: a binary column that indicates whether this date is a working day or not (e.g. if the day is weekend or holiday the value is 0 and otherwise 1)

**EmployeeCommitment** table does not contain the days where employees have no commitments which is quite reasonable since it only gets a new row when somebody commits to work and not the other way around.

But what I want to have is to get a row for each day that employees have not committed to any work. E.g. if employee `john.smith` has committed to only 3 days this week (`mon`, `tue`, `wed`), he should get two extra rows for `thu` and `fri` (let's say this is a normal week with no holidays) containing his name and a 0% commitment which will be a total of 5 rows for this week.

I have tried to join the two tables like this

```
SELECT * FROM  Calendar c LEFT JOIN EmployeeCommitment e ON c.Calendar_Date=EmployeeCommitment.Date
```

But this JOIN gives me `null` columns for the table on the right and there is no way of knowing which  employee they belong to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate all the rows using `cross join` and then bring in the information you want . . . for instance, using `left join`:

```
SELECT c.*, e.employee, COALESCE(ec.commitment, 0) as commitment
FROM Calendar c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT Employee FROM Employees e) e LEFT JOIN
     EmployeeCommitment ec
     ON c.Calendar_Date = ec.Date AND
        e.Employee = ec.Employee;
```